# result is null for multiple columns display in single column

Tags: excel, database, business-intelligence, business-objects

BI report: Currently 'part' column may have missing data for other columns. If entry for field( item 1, item 2)is null then display. Only want to Display null entries but in a single column where the missing data is listed.

Now:

```
Part    Item 1    Item 2   Item 3     Item 4
X        Buy        Null    Keep      Null
Y        Null       Sell    Null       Trash
```

Desired:

```
Part     Missing
X         Item 2, item 4
Y         Item 1, item 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable like this...

```
=If(IsNull([Item 1]); "Item 1, "; "") +
 If(IsNull([Item 2]); "Item 2, "; "") + 
 If(IsNull([Item 3]); "Item 3, "; "") +
 If(IsNull([Item 4]); "Item 4, "; "")
```

If you want to trim the final ", " off the end you can create another variable based on the first one like this...

```
=Substr([FirstVariable]; 1; Length([FirstVariable]) - 2)
```

Noel